# i3: background is not set

Tags: desktop-background

I am using `feh` to set the background on i3. Using the following command from terminal and it **works** fine:

```
feh --bg-fill /home/foo/image.png
```

So trying to set the background on startup via `~/.i3/config`:

```
exec --no-startup-id feh --bg-fill /home/foo/image.png
```

But it does not work. I checked the logs, on `/var/log/syslog` and i3 is complaining that the file does not exist:

```
Aug 19 08:00:19 9380 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11992]: feh WARNING:  /home/foo/image.png does not exist - skipping
Aug 19 08:00:19 9380 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[11992]: feh: No loadable images specified.
```

Any suggestions on what can be wrong? Is it permission that is wrong on some folders?

Comment: Make sure that the image exists. In i3 config put `exec --no-startup-id "feh --bg-fill /home/foo/image.png"` (note the quotes).

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz did not helpt to put quotes around :(